# Retopology and reflections issues (wrong normals)

Tags: shaders, normals, geometry, reflection, retopology

Retopology and reflections issues (wrong vertex normals)
I've started retopology. But I've noticed a problem. Although the topology seems to be clean, the reflection is completely broken compared to the original object. In my opinion this must be due to a vertex normals problem, but I don't know how to solve it. I've tried all the Alt+N menu and the Normal modifiers...
Does anyone know how to fix this?
[image]

[image]